# Imagebrush resolution to render a MeshGeometry3D in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am visualizing some spatial data using a MeshGeometry3D in WPF. I noticed that passing an ImageBrush to the constructor of DiffuseMaterial makes 3D visualization and manipulation fast and efficient (than say using a VisualBrush). My solution is in the following code block where this.dataMeshModel is a GeometryModel3D that includes the mesh. The problem is that I have to give very high resolutions (1000) to the Bitmap image source to make the grid look nice and distinguishable. Choosing this high dpi seems odd and easily raises memory exceptions. Any suggestion? The data model looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25206318/size%202.png) for 1000 dpi and [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25206318/size%203.png) for 4000 dpi. THANKS!

```
    private void assignTexture(Geometry gridGeom, double textureDPI, double gridThickness)
    {
        // rendering the grid on a DrawingVisual
        DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
        using (var dvc = dv.RenderOpen())
        {
            dvc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Tomato, null, gridGeom.Bounds);
            dvc.DrawGeometry(null, new Pen(Brushes.Black, gridThickness), gridGeom);
        }
        if (dv.Drawing.CanFreeze)
        {
            dv.Drawing.Freeze();
        }
        //rendering the DrawingVisual to an image
        Rect bounds = dv.ContentBounds;
        RenderTargetBitmap renderedBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            (int)(bounds.Width * this.textureDPI / 96),
            (int)(bounds.Height * this.textureDPI / 96),
            this.textureDPI,
            this.textureDPI,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderedBitmap.Render(dv);
        // adding the rendered image to create an imagebrush
        ImageBrush imBrush = new ImageBrush(renderedBitmap);
        //creating the material
        DiffuseMaterial dataMeshMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(imBrush);
        this.dataMeshModel.Material = this.dataMeshMaterial;
    }
```

Comment: so what's your actual problem? you have some performance issue?

Comment: Can I do anything to avoid this high resolution? It uses a lot of memory specifically when the data is large I may get an out of memory exception.